# Computer science classes and their strange feedback standards

Tags: computer-science, undergraduate

I'm young undergraduate kid who just stepped into the big world of computer science. I've had experience working as a developer at a companies and really liked it, and I decided that if I wanted to pursue Computer science seriously, that I should pursue an undergraduate degree in computer science.

A few quarters later, I'm utterly frustrated with how TAs and professors answer student questions regarding homework as vaguely as possible. For instance, a common pattern is "I don't understand how policy XYZ works in contexts A, B and C" is usually met with "It says XYZ in the assignment sheet." However, it seems that *all* the CS classes offered at my university follow this bizarre procedure of just telling the student to just read the assignment sheet.

The reason I'm so dumbfounded is because when I was working as a developer, questions like these were applauded and were answered with enthusiasm. In my other subjects, the same enthusiasm occurs. It just seems that computer science academia has this strange standard unique to all others.

Perhaps it's a product of how competitive it is, perhaps the professors and TAs just don't have time for thousands of student questions that have "obvious" answers. But I have to ask, **are the majority computer science courses at other universities like this as well?**

Comment: I don't understand your example/pattern. Can you elaborate? More explicitly, I don't get "policy XYZ". Grading policy? Something else?

Comment: Also, the question is subject to closure since you only have a yes-no question. The answer would logically be no, but that won't help you. What do you really need from the community here? Say more.

Comment: On one assignment, we were given a snippet of code that we were to use in our assignment. The assignment spec sheet wrote we were to use it "without modification." On top of that, we were to use some old code from a previous assignment "without modification." One student noted that the tabbing/comment format on the snippet provided by the professor differed from from their old assignment (we lose points if we're not consistent, but the professor has expressed they do not mind if our comment/tab standards are different from his) and what they should do. He was met with "Read the spec."

Comment: If the answer is "yes" then I'll suck it up. If the answer is "no" then I'll consider pursuing other universities/other majors. How did you conclude the answer is "logically no"? I'm unfamiliar with with the world of academia. I apologize if this sounds like a rant, I just thought appropriate backstory was warranted. Let me know if I should delete parts of it or rephrase parts of it.

Comment: I doubt that it is the university/department as a whole. I wonder if the TA has just been given instructions to give minimal help. Some professors might have such a policy. Some TAs might just interpret policy that way. Or just be clueless. Did you specifically point out the inconsistency? I doubt, however, that re-tabbing is considered a "change". I'm not in charge, of course.

Comment: "I doubt that it is the university/department as a whole." You have no idea how much relief you've brought me. As for your question, it's all on an online message board where all TAs and professors are active participants. I didn't explicitly say "look this clearly is contradictory" but you'd have to be very ... special .. not to immediately notice it. I also am inclined to agree with you, but if a professor keeps restating "without modification," you start to second guess yourself a lot.

Comment: I think what Buffy means is that since there are so many computer science courses at so many universities, it is inconceivable that they all have the property you describe. Hence the answer to your question is “no”. Although I suppose a rigorous proof of that would require giving a specific counterexample.

Comment: @DanRomik, my classes are a counterexample, but that doesn't help the OP. Also, I'm retired.

Comment: I'm wondering if the _majority_ of universities share these properties and if these properties are just going to be present as I climb the computer science academic ladder.

Comment: I don't understand your question. "It says XYZ in the assignment sheet." could be a very reasonable answer.

Comment: I've been advising CS teachers for years (in person and in print) to give complete feedback. I think you are in an anomalous situation but can't put my finger on why with just the information you've given. It now reads like a rant and not a question.

Comment: Apologies, feel free to close it then. I clearly need to spend more time in academia before questioning my professors!

Comment: Not at all. But you need to help us better understand the nature of the issue. Moreover, make us understand what it is you really need. The first answer (just given, below) may be great or terrible. I can't say without knowing more.

Comment: Incredibly common trope. Not restricted to CS. See the following (q.v., "This message brought to you by every instructor who ever lived"): http://phdcomics.com/comics.php?f=1583

Comment: And also this: https://www.zazzle.com/its_in_the_syllabus_t_shirt-235055245426509042

Comment: If its any consolation, the quality and helpfulness of any instructor - from personal experience in multiple academic settings - can range from "I can't believe you people are allowed to keep your job" to "I can't believe anyone can be as good at their job as you are at yours". I've experienced both of the extremes, and the vast majority of cases are in-between but mostly well to the positive side. Computer-related fields are some of the most tolerant of interpersonal "quirkiness", as is academia generally, so embracing a strategy of "how can I make the most of this" will aid your sanity :)

Comment: It is! This is just more evidence that I selected the right major! I'm happy to hear that I don't have to grit my teeth for the next few years, er, at least not for a majority of my cs classes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't really understand your question. However, I think there is something wrong with your premise:

> However, it seems that *all* the CS classes offered at my university follow this bizarre procedure of just telling the student to just read the assignment sheet.

This is not a bizarre procedure. It is entirely reasonable to expect students to read the assignment sheet.

Of course, you can and should ask questions when the assignment is unclear or there is an error in it. However, it sounds like the TAs don't think that is the case and they think you should just re-read it and think carefully.

Also the TAs cannot tell you the answers to your assignment. Perhaps the questions you are asking are effectively asking for the answers. If that is the case, then it is correct for the TAs to deflect back to the assignment sheet.

> when I was working as a developer, questions like these were applauded and were answered with enthusiasm.

When you were working as a developer, everyone is working together to solve the problem. A course is a different situation. TAs presumably know the answers, but they aren't going to give them to you. They are there to help you figure it out yourself.